# how to check the $refs in json schema are resolved correctly

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am trying to write a test suite that checks all my schema and verifies the `$ref` reference within each of the JSON file are resolved correctly. For example: consider this is a valid reference in a JSON

```
"title": "Response",
"description": "Schema descriptions of common properties of a response",
"type": [ "object" ],
"properties": {
  "_meta": {
     "$ref": "../Meta.json"
   },
  "operations": {
     "type": "string"
   
  },
  "bs":{
    "$ref": "file/bs.json"
  }  

}
```

I would like to check the references  `../Meta.json` and `file/bs.json` are resolved correctly and if the references are wrong (ex`.file/bills.json`) then the test should raise a ResolutionError.

```
def test_schema_ref(self):
    """
    Test whether or not the ref is valid
    """
    schema_files = self._get_schema_files()
    try:
        for schema_file in schema_files:
            base_uri = 'file://'+os.path.join(self._schema_dir, os.path.dirname(schema_file))
            referer = os.path.basename(schema_file)
            fpath = os.path.join(self._schema_dir, schema_file)
            resolver = RefResolver(base_uri, referer)
            if os.path.isfile(fpath):
                with open(fpath, "r") as schema_fd:
                    schema = json.load(schema_fd)
                    node = TestRefResolution._do_resolve(schema)`

    def _do_resolve(node):
        if isinstance(node, dict):
            for k, v in node.items():
                if k == 'properties' and isinstance(node[k], dict):
                    for key, value in node[k].items():
                        print ("key", key, value)
```

How should I check whether the refs resolve and is there a way to check for the refs recursively with in the `properties` and resolve them?

Comment: So what have you got so far, and what part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @ether, I had edited my question to add my code snippets.